# IF AND Excel formula convert to SQL or Python

Tags: python, sql

I have this IF(AND excel formula that I'm having trouble converting to Python or SQL.

excel formula = `(IF(AND(A3=A2,B3>B2),"Improve",IF(AND(A3=A2,B3<B2),"Not Improved",IF(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2),"No Change","-"))))`

DATA LOOKS LIKE
[excel formula / results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnSiG.jpg)

How would I re-write this formula to work in either SQL or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully supported in **numpy**

- **np.select()** or **np.where()** for **IF**
- array binary logic for **AND**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3])
b = np.array([17,17,10,8,14,15])

np.select([(np.roll(a, 1) == a) & (np.roll(b,1)<b),
           (np.roll(a, 1) == a) & (np.roll(b,1)>b),
           (np.roll(a, 1) == a) & (np.roll(b,1)==b),
          ], ["Improve", "Not improved", "No change"], "")
```

### output

```
array(['', 'No change', '', 'Not improved', '', 'Improve'], dtype='<U12')
```